# How do I reinstall the default (non-proprietary) display drivers?

Tags: drivers, video

I, I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my dual screen PC and everything worked flawlessly.

Then they asked me about proprietary drivers: ATI.

I said "ok install them".

Now it doesn't work on my dual screen anymore, I've got only one "duplicated" screen.

So, my question is: how to re-install the original video driver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To properly revert the graphic drivers to the out of the box state do the following commands in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Now reboot your system and everything will be fine.

Comment: Saved me from reinstalling!

Answer (score 1):

You would simply uninstall the display driver you have installed. Open `jockey-gtk` aka "Additional drivers", click on the activated driver and click remove (lower right corner). This should revert the settings to your former ones.