# Where is unity?

Tags: unity, drivers, 12.10, graphics, radeon

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. I installed updates and graphics card driver. after that, i lost desktop.

[image: http://imagesturk.net/images/2012/11/07/ALnly.png]

this is screenshot. no unity, panel and others. 
Driver = ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5430.
Driver Version v12.10

Comment: try my answer on this post to revert the graphics driver back to out of the box state http://askubuntu.com/questions/154063/how-do-i-reinstall-the-default-non-proprietary-display-drivers/154067#154067

Answer (score 0):

A well known problem with ATI on 12.10 !
I had the same problem with ATI 75xx card but disabling ATI proprietary driver and enabling X.org solved the problem. Anyway, I found this blog post [here](http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/) see if that could help.

You can always try disabling the ATI driver and activate the good old X.Org driver in **Software Sources >> Additional driver >> Use X.Org driver**

Comment: it didnt work. there is a package error for x.org driver !

Comment: is there any specif error displayed ? Maybe some more details on what and how did you do it ? Try updating the system first and see if there is any update for `X`.

Comment: i reinstalled 12.10. i updated everything. i installed x.org driver first. it worked. thank you for first way.

Answer (score 0):

I have also ati radeon hd 5450 and after installing its driver I had the same problem as you. But I solved it after performing following command:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

Hope it will help you. For more information you can read following resource here - [ATI Raden Ubuntu Quantal Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide) .

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in more than one place. When tempted to do so, this means that either: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), or (3) the answer should really be a comment, (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.