# Unity doesn't appear after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: unity, nvidia, 12.10

I've just installed 12.10 from scratch. Unity also started okay, but in a poor resolution. I found a setting (I think it was in "software sources") to change the display driver to Nvidia, and then I rebooted.

When Ubuntu now starts, it goes to the desktop (I see a file that I saved to the desktop) but there are no other screen elements -- no Unity, no menu bar at the top, no window decoration, nothing.

Ctrl-Alt-T and Ctrl-Alt-F2 work as they should, but it's kinda limiting...

1. How can I restore the default driver? I guess I need a way to open those "software sources" settings again - or anything else that could fix it! I hope I don't have to type [all this](https://askubuntu.com/a/154067/5786) by hand.
2. How can I install a proper Nvidia driver so that I can get up to 1280x1024? [My old tricks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100900/how-do-i-set-the-correct-monitor-resolution-with-nvidia-drivers-for-a-monitor-th) don't seem to work, but perhaps they might if I solve #1...

Comment: I had the same problem with ati 5450, which I eventually replaced with Nvidia Gt610 -- and got the same problem. Have just tried everything in this post with no success until ... I did: sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
And rebooted (ie. Without reinstalling nvidia-curent) Now I have unity back

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just went through this myself, the problem is that there is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1070427) in the Ubuntu installer that removes the Linux Headers needed for the Nvidia drivers to work.

You'll need to do the following:

From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic && sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If you don't see output from nvidia-current being installed then one of the first two commands failed.

You'll need to reboot, and once you do you'll be able to use your computer again.

Comment: Should I run `nvidia-xconfig` after the reinstall before I boot normally?

Comment: For me, installing Linux headers without reinstalling `nvidia-current` worked.

Answer (score 6):

To restore the default driver you have to uninstall the package `nvidia-current`. You can do this in your STTYs (Ctrl-Alt-F[1-6]).

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
```

Afterwards simply reboot and you should be fine.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me, complete removing `nvidia-current` worked. If i tried re-installing it, i would still have the same issue. This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The headers I have were newer than the kernel I was running. For that reason I had to upgrade my kernel version. Then, I would recommend the following procedure:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-source
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the proprietary driver from NVIDIA which doesn't work on Optimus laptops. All I had to do was running

```
sudo nvidia-uninstall
```

and removing /etc/X11/xorg.conf

OBS: You need to turn off X server to do that. Use ctrl+alt+f1 to go to "interfaceless" mode and type

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

After uninstalling run

```
sudo start lightdm
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, nothing helped until I ran this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove fglrx --purge
```

Comment: Just to note, `fglrx` is for ATI cards