# Installed kernel, and printer driver - No Unity?

Tags: 12.10, unity, boot, kernel

I ran installation of printer drives for Epson Stylus S22 (From original website)

The most recent installs are:

```
2013-04-10 12:06:53 install linux-image-3.5.0-27-generic:amd64 <none> 3.5.0-27.46
2013-04-10 12:07:05 install linux-image-extra-3.5.0-27-generic:amd64 <none> 3.5.0-27.46
2013-04-10 12:20:26 install libqt4-opengl:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1
2013-04-10 12:20:27 install dpkg-dev:all <none> 1.16.7ubuntu6
2013-04-10 12:20:28 install html2text:amd64 <none> 1.3.2a-15build1
2013-04-10 12:20:29 install po-debconf:all <none> 1.0.16+nmu2ubuntu1
2013-04-10 12:20:30 install dh-apparmor:all <none> 2.8.0-0ubuntu5
2013-04-10 12:20:30 install debhelper:all <none> 9.20120608ubuntu1
2013-04-10 12:20:32 install librpmio3:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-4ubuntu0.1
2013-04-10 12:20:33 install librpm3:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-4ubuntu0.1
2013-04-10 12:20:34 install librpmbuild3:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-4ubuntu0.1
2013-04-10 12:20:34 install librpmsign1:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-4ubuntu0.1
2013-04-10 12:20:35 install rpm-common:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-4ubuntu0.1
2013-04-10 12:20:36 install rpm2cpio:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-4ubuntu0.1
2013-04-10 12:20:36 install rpm:amd64 <none> 4.10.0-4ubuntu0.1
2013-04-10 12:20:37 install alien:all <none> 8.88
2013-04-10 12:20:38 install libstdc++6-4.7-dev:amd64 <none> 4.7.2-2ubuntu1
2013-04-10 12:20:40 install g++-4.7:amd64 <none> 4.7.2-2ubuntu1
2013-04-10 12:20:41 install g++:amd64 <none> 4:4.7.2-1ubuntu2
2013-04-10 12:20:43 install build-essential:amd64 <none> 11.5ubuntu3
2013-04-10 12:20:43 install heirloom-mailx:amd64 <none> 12.5-2
2013-04-10 12:20:44 install libc6-i386:amd64 2.15-0ubuntu20 2.15-0ubuntu20
2013-04-10 12:20:46 install lib32z1:amd64 <none> 1:1.2.7.dfsg-13
2013-04-10 12:20:47 install libalgorithm-diff-perl:all <none> 1.19.02-2
2013-04-10 12:20:47 install libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl:amd64 <none> 0.04-2build3
2013-04-10 12:20:48 install libalgorithm-merge-perl:all <none> 0.08-2
2013-04-10 12:20:49 install libjpeg62:amd64 <none> 6b1-2ubuntu2
2013-04-10 12:20:49 install libsys-hostname-long-perl:all <none> 1.4-2
2013-04-10 12:20:50 install libmail-sendmail-perl:all <none> 0.79.16-1
2013-04-10 12:20:51 install libqt4-gui:amd64 <none> 4:4.8.3+dfsg-0ubuntu3.1
2013-04-10 12:20:51 install m4:amd64 <none> 1.4.16-3
2013-04-10 12:20:52 install pax:amd64 <none> 1:20120606-2
2013-04-10 12:20:53 install lsb-invalid-mta:all <none> 4.0-0ubuntu26.1
2013-04-10 12:20:54 install lsb-core:amd64 <none> 4.0-0ubuntu26.1
2013-04-10 12:20:54 install lsb-graphics:amd64 <none> 4.0-0ubuntu26.1
2013-04-10 12:20:55 install lsb-cxx:amd64 <none> 4.0-0ubuntu26.1
2013-04-10 12:20:55 install lsb-desktop:amd64 <none> 4.0-0ubuntu26.1
2013-04-10 12:20:56 install lsb-printing:amd64 <none> 4.0-0ubuntu26.1
2013-04-10 12:20:57 install lsb:all <none> 4.0-0ubuntu26.1
```

After rebooting, I get to login screen. I proceed to login, and all I see was my background, and my mouse(I was able to open a terminal by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-  <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>. I suspected this to be my newly installed kernel. (3.5.0-27). I therefore rolled back, to -26 kernel. (Removing the image from /boot and running `update-grub2`)

Seeing I'm completely lost on this, I may not have given sufficient information. Feel free to comment, about any information, logs or anything you'll need.

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/215016/unity-doesnt-appear-after-installing-nvidia-drivers?rq=1 "the problem is that there is a bug in the Ubuntu installer that removes the Linux Headers needed for the Nvidia drivers to work." would match you installing  a new kernel...

Comment: Would this apply to ATi drivers too?