# Unity not loading on 13.04 with nvidia-current

Tags: nvidia, 13.04

The desktop environment loads (I can use ctrl+alt+T, for example) but neither the topbar nor the unity launcher appear on the desktop.

dmesg | grep NVIDIA

```
[    2.592879] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:26:46 PDT 2013
[    3.262291] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[    3.262293] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[    3.262295] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[    3.262295] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[    3.262296] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
```

sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep NVI

```
Apr 19 23:31:35 monster kernel: [    2.149532] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Apr 19 23:31:35 monster kernel: [    2.592879] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.88  Wed Mar 27 14:26:46 PDT 2013
Apr 19 23:31:36 monster kernel: [    3.262293] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
```

Tried this, https://askubuntu.com/a/215020. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Did you install it in the desktop environment or did you temporarily change the kernel command line and do a `text` boot and install it from text-based console?

Comment: Desktop environment. Although, I was able to to get it working by reseting compiz and reseting unity as per http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/how-to-reset-unity-compiz-in-ubuntu-12-10-and-13-04 I had to do it twice before anything popped. Seems to be working just fine now though (after 5 successful reboots)

Comment: Great. If you have any further issues, I strongly recommend the "experimental" 310 drivers (`nvidia-experimental-310`). I had a lot less issues with it than the "current" one. As far as I can tell (a couple of weeks of constant use, including TF2 gaming) the 310 drivers are perfect for me with GTX 580, but on 12.10 though.

Comment: I think that's the big difference. My understanding is that 12.04 /12.10 drivers for NV are pretty stable. 13.04 is still in beta (at least for a few more days), so I just wanted to throw it out there see if anyone had a fix.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen For kicks I tried installed the nvidia-current and yes, after that Unity does not load. i changed the video card (From 560ti to 460 to 9500) and the problem was still there). Had to again use the xorg ppa. I would recommend going here and doing the PPA from Xorg first http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/driver-to-use-when-installing-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card

Comment: All I did was reset unity a few times and it popped up. I think it  might have been a collision with `unity tweak` options that I had set previously.

Answer (score 1):

For me, resetting compiz and unity a few times worked.

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown
```

Comment: Now that you have answered your own question, accept your answer to the question, so that it can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**nvidia-xconfig** should fix this. I provide more details in [my answer to Unity not loading on 13.04 with nvidia-current](https://askubuntu.com/a/309054/22808).