# Ubuntu 16.04 installed AMD Drivers -oops

Tags: drivers, graphics, 16.04, amd-graphics

I upgraded Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 today... I wasn't thinking today, definitely failed to read the myriad of warning signs to not install AMD drivers -- but I did LOL *facepalm*

*Note: I downloaded and installed directly from AMD.COM (http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux)*

now I boot to a 640x480 Login screen. When I login, it just give a error message too quick to read, and immediately I'm back at the login screen.

Please help

*edit:*

- I tried all apt-get purge and apt-get remove, but it says nothing's installed
- I followed this page too  http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf

Comment: See if pressing ctrl+alt+f2, logging in and running `sudo apt-get purge fglrx-*` does. Reboot.

Comment: Thanks I tried those, edited my page to show that... and it said 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded

Comment: Try `sudo aticonfig --uninstall`.

Comment: Thanks again, that reports: "No supported adapters detected"

Comment: What about `sudo sh amd-driver-installer-x86.x86_64.run --uninstall`? Run this in the directory of the downloaded driver.

Comment: Ok that worked for the resolutions problem, thanks!!! However, I still cannot login

Comment: I found that the non-proprietary drivers work for me .. AMD on-board graphics on an older MB ..  you can try [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154063/how-do-i-reinstall-the-default-non-proprietary-display-drivers) to maybe rid yourself of the proprietary ones and install the non ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-x86.x86_64.run --uninstall
```

in the directory where the driver installer was downloaded.

It will remove the driver and your resolution will be back to normal.

Comment: This fixed the resolution, but I still can not login