# Graphical environment dies on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, environment

I'm actually using Kubuntu 16.04 with KDE Plasma 5.8.

It runs normally, but, when I play a game or after an 1 hour or less of of PC turn on, the graphical environment dies without any way to reboot it through command line or similar.

When that happends, I must to reboot the machine again shutting down or rebooting manually with the reboot button, I don't konw why happends that, so any idea how to fix it or what I must to install to fix that issue?

Comment: Please identify the hardware of system including type of video card/GPU.  It is possible system is running out of video memory or running into video compatibility issue.

Comment: Hi there, my machine have a intel core2 duo 7500, 4 gb ram, and a nvidia 710 2gb.

Comment: Besides, I installed a 2k monitor, Lg (25" Class 21:9 UltraWide® Full HD IPS LED Monitor).

Comment: To prevent corrupting the system with a hard reset, consider installing an ssh server (`apt-get install openssh-server`) and connecting to the machine via another system. `sudo shutdown -r now` can be used for a controlled soft-restart.  While logged in, one can also attempt to diagnose by checking various logs for specific errors.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, however, I don't have another way to use other system to do that you explain me, there's another way to do something?

Comment: Hi there community. About my problem with this, the graphical environment dies and this error appear: INITRAMFS error.  I fixed with command "fsck -yv"however, the systems continues crashing, so, there's a any way to reinstall the graphical environment or fix this issue?

Comment: Hi JESUS0414. "Another system" does not have to be a computer. Many smart phones have ssh capability via an app.  To help with a more specific diagnoses, try following these instructions to show additional information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicsTroubleshootingProcedure best wishes

Comment: Hi community. The issu e was resolved junt installing the nvidia privative driver for the control of graphic environment.

Comment: @JESUS414 try https://askubuntu.com/a/154068